# How can I clientside export HTML to PDF using PhoneGap1.4 Xcode4.2 HTML5

Tags: javascript, xcode, html, cordova, export-to-pdf

I'm using Xcode v4.2, PhoneGap v1.4 and Mac v10.7.1. My application is working fine.

How can I export the current HTML page to PDF? I want to place a button `exportToPdf` on top bar.

I have tried jspdf but it successfully export page in browser Firefox without PhoneGap.
But I need this functionality with phonegap.

Comment: I have found no answer and im googling for 6 hours im stuck in an application every functionality is finished except export to pdf

Comment: If you have jsPDF working in a browser, what is stopping it from working in PhoneGap? Have you actually tried it? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using XSL-FOP?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37663/PDF-Generation-using-XSLFO-and-FOP

Comment: sorry but i need clientside export html page to pdf in html page functionality